# How to delay an annotation in mapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have two locations in my app. The fist one in Europe and the second in America.

When my app loads, the fist location region is visible and the little red ball annotation goes down animated. But, when I push a button that takes me to the second location, the app takes me there but when the new region appears the second location annotation is already there.

Is there any way to delay the new annotation animation and show it only when the new region is visible?

Probably when the map goes from location 1 to location 2 the animation occurs.

Note: When I set the second locations nearer from location 1 the annotation animations works perfectly and I'm able to see it.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: I would say - remove all annotations, and add them back with the new location (or) have a method that setsAnnotationForLocation:(CALocation*) location. That way - annotations are displayed as and when you pass a location.

Comment: I'll try it out... I'll let you know if it works. Thanx!

Comment: I tried to remove all annotations and adding back only the one I'm using and worked fine! Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you could use an `NSTimer`.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(Amount of Time you want before the method) target:self selector:@selector(MethodName) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

This just says, Run the `@selector(method)` after `(Amount of Time you want...)` and `repeats:NO` says it will happen once then never again.

This should work, but you will need to make a new method to make the annotation and call that method up here.